# Automatically give lambda arguments

Tags: python-3.x, input, lambda

Say I don't know in advance how many arguments my lambda function will take. Let's say I code something which asks the user how many arguments I want:

```
num = input('How many args? ')
num =  float(num)
```

Say, the user inputs 4. How would I then do something like this in a function?

```
func=lambda x,y,z,t : eval(string)
```

Automatically -- I must stress. I need to have Python give 4 dummy variables in this case to the lambda function (I happened to denote it x,y,z,t as the dummies) just because I've specified `num = 4`. The user will specify the function of x,y,z,t with a string such as `"x+y+z+t"`. Is this possible?

Comment: When you're dealing with *many* items, the natural *data structure* of choice is a `list`. I see no reason to have a n-arity function when there's a direct correspondence to a function accepting a list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version, I didn't use a function at all, I just used exec to dynamically define variable names so the eval will work then:

```
var_names = ["x", "y", "z", "t"]

arg_num = int(input('How many args? '))

for i in range(arg_num):
    exec(var_names[i] + "=" + input(var_names[i] + "= "))

print(eval(input("provide func ")))
```

Comment: Would this work with something like `eval(string)`? I just need the user to input the function as a string. Could you provide a loose example?

Comment: can you precise a bit how your interface would work, i have trouble understanding how it's supposed to work

Comment: Basically would something like `def my_func(*args,string):
    return lambda *args : eval(string)` or `def my_func(*args,string):
    return eval(string)` work?

Comment: I'm trying to have the user state there are 3 variables and input a formula as a string like something like 'x + y + z**2' and then Python creates a function with 3 arguments that returns `x+y+z**2`

Comment: How would you map the variables ? it's a predefined order ?

Comment: Why does it *need* to be a named function? You can do the exact same thing with lambdas.

Comment: My bad, I thought it was not possible with lambda. However, with what the author wants to try, it looks a bit hard to do that.

Comment: Regardless if it can or can't could either be explained/provided in an example?

Comment: I modified my answer to provide a working script. The `+` to do string concatenation is not very pythonic, you should probably refactor with something better

Comment: @Axnyff Is there a modification for this where x, y, z values are given in an array?

Comment: I don't understand, you want the user to also define its variables ? If so it would probably work with an eval of input to define what is var_names